# how maven read the comment in a plugin Mojo

Tags: maven, plugins

I am developing a maven plugin.

when see a plugin demo like below, I felt strange about how maven can get the comment(not annotation) at run time. Isn't comment is erased at compile-time?

```
public class HelloWorldMojo extends AbstractMojo {  

    /** 
     * @parameter expression="${name}" 
     * @required 
     */  
    String name;  

    /** 
     * @parameter expression="${age}" 
     * @required 
     */  
    int age;  

    /** 
     * @parameter expression="${isOk}" 
     * @required 
     */  
    boolean isOk;  

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {  
     .....
    }  

}
```

Comment: I think the maven-plugin-plugin reads this (similar to what javadoc does) and generates the plugin.xml accordingly. It's not done during runtime. There are newer versions available that do the same using annotations but the data is still created during the build and not collected at runtime.

Comment: First you should avoid using XDoctlet. Better use [annotations](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html) which is available for a very long time. Furthermore the information of the docs is extracted by [QDox](https://github.com/paul-hammant/qdox) which is used by the plugin-tools. QDox parses the source code...